# Angular Universal AngularOpenlayersModule

Tags: angular4, openlayers

Если собирать приложение без рендеринга на стороне сервера, то оно собирается и запускается. Карты работают отлично. Но если попробовать собрать их с рендерингом на стороне сервера, то приложение собирается, но не запускается, выдает ошибку

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Я знаю, что Angular Universal не работает напрямую с document и window. Но ошибку с document можно обойти

```
constructor( @Inject( DOCUMENT ) private document: any) {
  ...
}
```

и это если мой код, то как обойти работу с window в openlayers\dist\ol.js (AngularOpenlayersModule).

Я могу конечно пожертвовать рендерингом на стороне сервера. И тогда карты будут работать, но тогда не получиться репостить данные например в ВК. Так как он не будут правильно отображать страницу.